# PHP: Secure way to store information into cookies?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm working on a log in system for an application, and I'm not sure what information I should store. Currently, I only store user's ID into a session variable, and if that variable is set, it will load the user from the database with all of the required information. But, I also want to have a 'remember me' option, for which I would require cookies, and I'm not sure what to store in them. If were only to store the user id, that would be risky, since someone could just change the id and be a different user. My idea currently is to do this:

```
$array = array($user['username'], $user['pass']);
            serialize(base64_encode($array));
```

So if the cookie was set, I would unserialize it, and find the user with the password and username (the password itself is hashed in MD5).
But, I assume this isn't very secure. What should I store into the cookie to make it secure, and is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting the password in the cookie, you can create a hash from it and save that instead. You would also save the hash in the database so when comparing cookies, the username and hash have to match which avoids exposing the password.

You can create a simple hash with [MD5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php).

Comment: You didn't read the whole question. Anyhow, I already hashed the password, before it was stored into the cookie, and when I check for the cookie, I login the user using the hashed password. Does that mean it's secure?

Comment: What @cillosis meant was, mostly, to save the session data in the database along with a random hash (do **not** store user data in a cookie, as it allows for easier session hijacking), preferrably sha256. The hash is stored in a cookie so that the session data can be restored if the cookie is present and valid. Also, md5 is not considered safe.